# SQL left join returns nothing when no matches

Tags: sql, join

I am writing a stored procedure that adds the counts to two fields. I have the following code:

```
    SELECT Distinct DateTime1,SUM(TICKETREQ1)SUMREQ, SUM(TicketPU1)SUMPU1, (count(*))AS GRADCOUNT
    FROM TABLEA
    WHERE YEAR = '2015'
        AND TicketReq1 > 0
        group by DateTime1

    Select DISTINCT(DateTime2),SUM(TicketReq2) SUMREQ,SUM(TicketPU2)SUMPU2, (count(*))AS GRADCOUNT
    from TABLEA
    where TicketReq2 > 0
        and YEAR = '2015'
        Group by DateTime2;


SELECT Distinct c.DateTime1,SUM(c.TICKETREQ1 + b.TicketReq2)SUMREQ, SUM(c.TicketPU1 + b.TicketPU2)SUMPU1, (count(b.id) + count(c.id))AS GRADCOUNT
FROM TABLEA c
LEFT JOIN TABLEA b 
    ON (b.DateTime2 = c.DateTime1
    AND b.TicketReq2 > 0
    AND b.YEAR = '2015')
WHERE c.YEAR = '2015'
AND c.TicketReq1 > 0
group by c.DateTime1
```

This returns: 
[image]

For some ceremonies the second query does bring in results and adds them correctly. But if there are no records then it fails.

[image]

How can I get it to join the two counts together (Query 1 and 2) so that Query 3 displays both counts even when there is no match

Comment: The problem could be in your SUM statements on query #3. b.TicketReq2 is null, therefore SUM(c.TICKETREQ1 + b.TicketReq2) should encounter an error. Try ISNULL(b.TicketReq2, 0) and similar changes in the other SUM and COUNT functions.

Comment: thanks works perfectly. I just assumed it would treat a null as a 0

Comment: I just needed to add the ISNULL to the sum function. ISNULL wasn't needed for the count function

Comment: I will add a formal answer in that case. Hopefully you'll come back and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: never ever ever ever use "select distinct" when you are also using GROUP BY, the "distinct" in all your queries above is utterly redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `SUM` statements on query #3. `b.TicketReq2` is null, therefore `SUM(c.TICKETREQ1 + b.TicketReq2)` should encounter an error. Try using `ISNULL(b.TicketReq2, 0)` in your `SUM` function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try full outer join instead of left join

```
SELECT Distinct c.CeremonyDateTime1,SUM(c.TICKETREQ1 + b.TicketReq2)SUMREQ, SUM(c.TicketPU1 + b.TicketPU2)SUMPU1, (count(b.gid) + count(c.gid))AS GRADCOUNT
FROM ComTicket c
FULL OUTER JOIN ComTicket b 
ON (b.CeremonyDateTime2 = c.CeremonyDateTime1
AND b.TicketReq2 > 0
AND b.Gradterm = '201540')
WHERE c.gradterm = '201540'
AND c.TicketReq1 > 0
group by c.CeremonyDateTime1
```

It might helpful to you..

Comment: remove the "distinct", it is useless when uniqueness is guaranteed by the group by